# ASP.NET MVC Route by first (nameless) query string-parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a SAP Content-Server using ASP.NET MVC 5.
Sap calls URIs with the following scheme to access Content-Server functions.

http://servername:port/***script***?**command**&parameters

The first queryString value ["command" in the example-Uri above] maps to a action-method, while "scipt" should map the controller.

The following Uri
http://MyServer/MyApp/ContentServer?info&pVersion=0045&contRep=K1&docId=361A524A3ECB5459E0000800099245EC

should be handled by the action-method "info" in controller "ContentServerController"

```
 public class ContentServerController : Controller
 {            
     public ActionResult info(string contRep, string docId, string pVersion)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of fabiosilvalima helped me to solve the problem

```
public class ContentServerController : Controller
{  
     // one public Action-Method which reads the "command" from query-string
     // and calls different private methods according to commandName          
     public ActionResult ContentServer(string contRep, string docId, string pVersion)
     {
         string commandName = Request.QueryString[0];
         switch(commandName)
         {
             case "info":
                 return info(contRep, docId, pVersion);
             case "get":
                 return get(contRep, docId, pVersion);
             case "create":
                 return create(contRep, docId);
             default:
                 throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
     }

     private ActionResult info(string contRep, string docId, string pVersion)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
     private ActionResult get(string contRep, string docId, string pVersion)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }  
     private ActionResult create(string contRep, string docId)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If first querystring it's the action, have you tried to do that:

```
public class ContentServerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string contRep, string docId, string pVersion)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(Request.QueryString[0]);
    }

    public ActionResult info(string contRep, string docId, string pVersion)
    {
        return Content("info action");
    }
}
```

PS: you need to check querystring length and malicious string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get hold of the non-standard parameter values:

```
public class ContentServerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = new List<string>();
        foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            data.Add("key=[" + (key ?? "--null--") + "], value=[" + Request.QueryString[key] + "]");
        }
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

... combined with this `Index` View:

```
@model List<string>
<a href="/ContentServer?info&pVersion=0045&contRep=K1&docId=361A524A3ECB5459E0000800099245EC">Link 1</a><br />
<a href="/ContentServer?about&foo=true&bar=false">Link 2</a><br />
<a href="/ContentServer?login&secure=yes">Link 3</a><br />
<hr size="1" />
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var str in Model)
    {
        @str<br />
    }
}
```

From there it is up to you to decide if you want to do a big `switch()` statement on `Request.QueryString[null]`, or `RedirectToAction("~/" + Request.QueryString[null]?" + all other parameters` plus corresponding Action methods, or whatever solution suits you best.